# How to solve OneSignal Error: "Segment is not a valid filter field"

Tags: java, filter, push-notification, tags, onesignal

I want to set a `filter` when sending a push notification through OneSignal.

When trying to set a `field` with `tag` get an 400-Error saying **"Segment  is not a valid filter field."**

I sent this body:

`{"contents":{"en":"only for meeeee"},"headings":{"en":"teeeest"},"filters":[{"type":"tag","value":"CUSTOMER","key":"userType","relation":"="}],"app_id":"41729389-3212-3123-bd5c-c687jjj334e7ea"}`

I expect that this works because my User has excectly this CUSTOMER tag.

result: `{"errors":["Segment  is not a valid filter field."]}`

What am I doing wrong?

There is nothing which has to do with segment in the body above.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:

There was a problem with the toStringMethod() of my Pojo which produced the wrong "field" - Name...instead it produced "type"...and this just in combination with JSONobject....VERY VERY weired!! This is an issue. Just changed the first variable which is read in the toStringMethod of my Pojo to "field" and it worked...